# How can I accept bug reports and other user feedback from within my app?

Tags: android, forum, bug-tracking

How can I accept feedback like bug reports, suggestions, and comments from my users in-app?

From what I can tell, the Android platform and Play offer no solutions for issue tracking or forums.

To clarify, I'm not looking for a way to submit crash reports exclusively, and I'm not looking to track user behavior.  I'm looking for a way for users to report unexpected behavior, ideas for enhancements, etc.

Comment: had you try ACRA? at least for bugs....

Comment: You can send an email from the app to yourself.

Comment: Try probably Google analytics for android. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide. Add a feedback form in your app that will send feedbacks with device id to your web server. Log bugs and send them once a day to the same web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to try out [UserVoice](http://www.uservoice.com) with their [REST API](http://developer.uservoice.com/).

Answer (score 6):

You could make use of [Instabug’s](http://instabug.com) SDK. It includes several features which are 
all relevant to your concerns:

- Bug reporting - allows users to report bugs through a shake gesture.
- Crash Reporting - automatically gets sent whenever one occurs.
- In-app Chat - have a live conversation with your users in-app to get 
  more feedback.
- Feature Requests - allow users to suggest new features and upvote existing ideas.
- In-App Surveys - Survey your users right inside your app with text multiple choice, or star rating questions.

---

For full disclosure, I work at Instabug. Let me know if I can help.

Answer (score 0):

For bug reports you can use [Airbrake](https://airbrake.io/pages/home). The good thing about this one is that you can add custom information. Moreover you can send a report at any time in your app (say you found a weird situation that you need to notify about).

For analytics, [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) worked well for me. It's simple but to the point.

Ultimately, you can use both for the major platforms so that you have everything in one place.

Comment: Airbrake appears to be for ios.

Comment: I'm currently using Airbrake for Android.